# Django ORM query returns wrong number of items

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm

In my application users can create lists and add influencers to them. My **User** and **InfluencerList** models have M2M relation. **InfluencerList** model have also M2M relation with **InstagramInfluencer**, **YoutubeInfluencer**, ...

Here is my query for getting users all lists and influencer counts in it, which works finely:

```
users_all_lists = request.user.lists.all().annotate(
               instagram_count=Count('influencers', distinct=True), 
               youtube_count=Count('youtube_influencers', distinct=True), 
               tiktok_count=Count('tiktok_influencers', distinct=True), 
               twitch_count=Count('twitch_influencers', distinct=True), 
               clubhouse_count=Count('clubhouse_influencers', distinct=True)
               ).values(
                   'id', 'name', 'instagram_count', 'youtube_count', 'tiktok_count', 'twitch_count', 'clubhouse_count', 
                   ).distinct().order_by('created_at')
```

I also want to return those influencers usernames, so I added foreign key lookups to `.values()` function:

```
users_all_lists = request.user.lists.all().annotate(
               instagram_count=Count('influencers', distinct=True), 
               youtube_count=Count('youtube_influencers', distinct=True), 
               tiktok_count=Count('tiktok_influencers', distinct=True), 
               twitch_count=Count('twitch_influencers', distinct=True), 
               clubhouse_count=Count('clubhouse_influencers', distinct=True)
               ).values(
                   'id', 'name', 'instagram_count', 'youtube_count', 'tiktok_count', 'twitch_count', 'clubhouse_count', 
                   # ADDED THIS ONE LINE BELOW
                   'influencers__username', 'tiktok_influencers__username', 'youtube_influencers__channel_title', 'twitch_influencers__username', 'clubhouse_influencers__username' 
                   ).distinct().order_by('created_at')
```

When a User has one InfluencerList with 2 influencers in it, this query returns 2 items which is not what I expected. Here is my InfluencerList model if it's necessary:

```
class InfluencerList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name:', unique=True, max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lists')
    influencers = models.ManyToManyField('Influencer', related_name='lists', blank=True)
    tiktok_influencers = models.ManyToManyField('TiktokInfluencer', related_name='lists', blank=True)
    youtube_influencers = models.ManyToManyField('YoutubeInfluencer', related_name='lists', blank=True)
    twitch_influencers = models.ManyToManyField('TwitchInfluencer', related_name='lists', blank=True)
    clubhouse_influencers = models.ManyToManyField('ClubhouseInfluencer', related_name='lists', blank=True)
```

I have spent much time in Django ORM documentation, but still struggling, so I appreciate any kind of help

Comment: so you are grouping -> group by  influencers__username. Why do you think your result should look anything different than it looks like.

Comment: It returns [ List A, Influencer X, List A, Influencer Y] ; but I want [List A, [Influencer X, Influencer Y]]. 1 item is what I want, not 2.